# How to add multiple tags in xml?

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples

First time handling XML files in python.
I would like to know how to add multiple child elements from a dictionary, for example, I have a child element called country, but I would like to create 40 elements with country tag, same with cities:
I have a tupple like this:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

dict={'Mexico':'CDMX','US':'Washington','France':'Paris','Japan':'Tokio'}
```

**How can I create multiple tags with same reference and how can I pass the value from the dictionary?(I can create the xml file but just with one tag.)**

I'm focusing on countries but I can't achieve to generate them by key this:

```
root = ET.Element("world")

country_tag = ET.SubElement(root, "country")
city = ET.SubElement(country_tag, "city")

for key,value in dict.items():
   ET.Element.append(country)
   country.text = str(key)
tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write("filename.xml", encoding="UTF-8",xml_declaration=True)
```

I would like to generate the following:

```
<world>
    <country>Mexico</country>
        <city>CDMX</city>
    <country>US</country>
        <city>Washington</city>
    <country>France</country>
        <city>Paris</Paris>
    <country>Japan</country>
        <city>Tokio</city>
</world>
```

I'm using python 3.7
I also need to know how to pass keys and values from my dictionary to xml tags. PLEASE, I NEED HELP!!!

Comment: So what is `ET`?

Comment: ET stands for ElementTree, using xml ElementTree